# Not able to retrieve data when converting docx to html in pandoc, styling, alignment is lost and table of contents and pagebreak also lost:

Tags: html, node.js, docx, pandoc

command looks likes this

```
const command = `pandoc -s "${filePath}" -t html -o "${outputPath}" --metadata title="." --extract-media=${htmlFilePath}  `;
```

any help me out or suggest me better parser/ convertor to convert docx files to html?

Comment: Pandoc aims to preserve the structure of a document, not the styling. Use Word or LibreOffice to export to HTML.